How are Toga and Twice able to say they won’t betray the yakuza to Nemoto?
I think it was episode 74 or 73 of the anime where Shin Nemoto used his confession quirk on Toga and Twice to get them to tell the yakuza the details of their quirks.
However, when he asks if they plan to betray the yakuza, they both say no, even though it was revealed that they were going to in a flashback.
How are they able to say no?

In the flashback in question (Ch 149 / Ep 73) Shigaraki never explicitly expressed intent to betray the Shie Hassaikai (AKA the MHA Yakuza).
Nemoto's quirk Confession forces its target to truthfully answer his questions to the letter. He demonstrates the quirk's power by causing Toga and Twice to reveal the details of their quirks. He then asks the question "does Shigaraki have any plans to betray us?" to which both of them say no. This reassures Overhaul (especially since the League wouldn't have known the Hassaikai had a lie detector quirk they ought to be wary of) that the pair do not know of any plans by Shigaraki to betray them. However Toga and Twice after providing some token help battling the heroes do indeed betray the Hassaikai by helping the heroes defeat Mimic and then skipping out on the alliance. This seems weird given their denial that Shigaraki planned any funny business but its true that Shigaraki never told them to do this, but it might be better to say he didn't need to.
Actually rewinding to the flashback (Ch 149), Shigaraki tells Toga and Twice to join the Hassaikai for a while since their plans seem promising. Both of them are against the idea, Jin hates the Hassaikai for killing Magne and feels responsible for introducing Overhaul to them while Toga finds the idea "unpleasant". Shigaraki brings them around by telling them "I believe in you two", he does not say anything to the effect of "we'll get our revenge", he doesn't have to. He knows that Twice wants to take responsibility for screwing up and Toga dislikes unpleasant things. This is demonstrated in Toga and/or Twice's quote the moment they turn on the Hassaikai (Ch 148) "Shigaraki... I still don't understand what you were thinking at the time. But you said you believed in us. And if that's the case, then for the sake of me being who I am, thinking what I still think... I'm going to do things the way I want". They don't know if Shigaraki has anything planned and they certainly don't have orders so they just follow their hearts and turn on the Hassaikai.
Ultimately Nemoto asked the wrong question, instead of "does Shigaraki plan to betray us?" he should've asked "do you plan to betray us?". He didn't because he fundamentally misunderstands the nature of the League of Villains, unlike the Hassaikai with their rigid chain of command where Overhaul's word is law, the League is nominally led by Shigaraki but aren't expected to follow orders unflinchingly, instead acting on shared understandings and loosely held together by an offbeat camaraderie.

@Gatchwat Ep 73 20:23 “I want you guys to flatter them up close and conquer them” It might be an error with the English subtitles, but that sounds like Shigaraki told Toga and Twice to betray the yakuza to me.

@Daemons so I checked out the episode and the subtitle is indeed that, "I want you guys to flatter them up close and conquer them, I never viewed them as equals", which is pretty sus for them to then state Shigaraki isn't plotting anything. The equivalent line in the manga (ch 148 pg 12) is much shorter "From the beginning they haven't viewed us as equals", which is mainly just Shigaraki saying aloud this was never going to be an equal partnership. I don't know the nuances of the Japanese in question but either way Toga and Twice do express their betrayal is their own call right after.
